# Determinant of huge block matrix

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, determinant, block-matrices

I need to calculate the determinant of the $3j \times 3j$ symmetric block matrix
$$\mathsf A_{j} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathsf T_j & \mathsf V_j & \mathsf 0_j \\
-\mathsf V_j & \mathsf T_j & \mathsf 0_j \\
\mathsf 0_j & \mathsf 0_j & \mathsf T_j
\end{bmatrix},$$
where
$$\mathsf T_j = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & & \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \\
 & -1 & 2 & \\
& & & \ddots \end{bmatrix}, \qquad \mathsf V_j =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \eta & & \\
-\eta & 0 & \eta & \\
 & -\eta & 0 & \\
& & & \ddots \end{bmatrix}, \quad \eta \in \mathbb R. $$
I have managed to calculate $\det \mathsf T_j = j+1$, so that
$$ \det \mathsf A_j = (j+1) \det \begin{bmatrix}
\mathsf T_j & \mathsf V_j  \\
-\mathsf V_j & \mathsf T_j
\end{bmatrix},$$
but the last determinant seems way too difficult to evaluate. I would be satisfied with a recurrence relation for the sequence $a_j := \det \mathsf A_j$, but that seems to be just as difficult.

Comment: For tridiagonal matrices like you have them, i.e. of the form $$\pmatrix{a&b&0&\cdots&0\\c&a&b&\ddots&\vdots\\0&c&a&\ddots&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&b\\0&\cdots&0&c&a} \in\ \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$, you can give a recursion formula for the determinant: $$\begin{align}d_1&=a,\\
d_2&=a^2-bc\\
d_n&=a d_{n-1}-bc d_{n-2}, n > 2\end{align}$$ You can further simplify the formula for both $V_j$ and $T_j$ to a concrete formula (you can also do that for the general tridiagonal matrix given above).

Comment: @Sudix Isn't there maybe some way to reduce $\mathsf A_j$ to a three-diagonal matrix itself? Possibly through orthogonal matrices? Then I'd be able to use your formula for the whole matrix